# Рекурсивная сумма из n чисел

Tags: python

Зачем в крайнем случае возвращают изначальный num, а не 1? Но считает правильно

```
def sum(num: int) -> int:
    if num <= 1:
        return num
    return num + sum(num - 1)
```

Comment: Для правильной обработки `sum(0)`. В остальных случаях можно возвращать единицу.

Comment: Лично мне кажется более логично писать `if num == 0: return 0`. Обычно стараются начальное условие располагать как можно "левее".

Comment: если num может быть только положительным, то мне тоже кажется, что возвращать 0 более очевидно: `return num + sum(num-1) if num else 0`